# How can I make my discord bot assign roles to users (discord js)

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

How can I assign roles to users with my discord js bot?

How can I make my discord bot assign roles to users (discord js)

I want it so that when I type !addrole a role gets added

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot Online');
});

var prefix = "!"

client.on(`message`, message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "addrole"))
  {
    //ADD ROLE HERE
  }

});

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity(`!help`, { type: "PLAYING" });
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the role you want to add:

```
const guild = message.guild;
let role = message.mentions.roles.first() || guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id === message.content.substring(1))
```

Then you add the role using:

```
const member = message.member
member.roles.add(role);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the version you are using but seeing that you are using indents you should try with this.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot Online');
});

var prefix = "!"

client.on(`message`, message => {
  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "addrole"))
  {
    const roleId = 'add your role id here'
    message.member.addRole(message.guild.roles.cache.find(roleId))
  }

});

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity(`!help`, { type: "PLAYING" });
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add role by message command

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents,FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE] });
client.on("message", (msg) => {
   // The roles that you can assign must be under bot roles. 
   const roleId = 'Your roles id'
   msg.member.addRole(message.guild.roles.cache.find(roleId))
})
```

Comment: This is practically identical to [this answer from last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73867222/19068), only without meeting all the requirements specified in the question. Try not to post answers that don't *add* anything, they just make it harder to find the good answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).